# Eulermath font in beamerposter

Tags: fonts, beamerposter

I'd like to use eulermath as a mathematical font for a beamerposter.

The reason is that I wrote my thesis using the ClassicThesis style with the option [eulermath].

I can't find a way to use it without using ClassicThesis.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `classicthesis.sty` one finds

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@eulermath}}%
    {\PassOptionsToPackage{euler-digits}{eulervm}%
     \RequirePackage{eulervm}} % Euler math fonts
    {\relax}
```

so, the `eulermath` option loads the `eulervm` package with the `euler-digits` option. If you want to have these settings in your beamerposter, simply load the `eulervm` package and use the `professional fonts` font theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]